# Axi2 client made with wsdl2Java uses UTF-8 instead of UTF-16

Tags: character-encoding, apache-axis

I'm using Axis2 1.6.1 to create a webservice, both the server and the client. The webservice is pretty simple: it receives two strings and returns an array of bytes. The issue I'm finding is that the client is sending the request encoded as UTF-8, so when I send a text in Spanish with accents, they get replaced by some strange characters. How can I force the client to use UTF-16?

Thanks

Jose Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set it as a service client property. Please have a look at here[1].

[1] http://wso2.org/library/230